# C Warning: No return statement in function returning non-void

Tags: c

I am trying to modify open-vm-tools,and it's work in Linux.
However, I get a "No return" error when I use Nmake.

> no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]

It seems that I lose a return word in this function. But there is return word in the bottom of the function. In order to solve the problem, I'v added a 'retrun 0' in line 17. It works,but the following code after 'return 0' won't be executed. That is not what I want. Here is the function:

```
static int
ToolsCoreRunLoop(ToolsServiceState *state)
{

    if (!ToolsCore_InitRpc(state)) {
      return 1;
    }

    if (state->ctx.rpc && !RpcChannel_Start(state->ctx.rpc)) {
      return 1;
    }

    if (state->ctx.rpc) {
      ToolsCoreReportVersionData(state);
    }

    //return 0; Here is what I add

    #if 0
    if (!ToolsCore_LoadPlugins(state)) {
      return 1;
    }
    #if defined(__linux__)
    if (state->mainService) {
      ToolsCore_InitVsockFamily(state);
    }  
    #endif
    if (state->ctx.errorCode == 0 &&
       (state->ctx.isVMware ||
        ToolsCore_GetTcloName(state) == NULL ||
        state->debugPlugin != NULL)) {
        ToolsCore_RegisterPlugins(state);

        if (g_signal_lookup(TOOLS_CORE_SIG_IO_FREEZE,
                      G_OBJECT_TYPE(state->ctx.serviceObj)) != 0) {
          g_signal_connect(state->ctx.serviceObj,
                      TOOLS_CORE_SIG_IO_FREEZE,
                      G_CALLBACK(ToolsCoreIOFreezeCb),
                      state);
        }

        state->configCheckTask = g_timeout_add(CONF_POLL_TIME * 1000,
                                         ToolsCoreConfFileCb,
                                         state);

        #if defined(__APPLE__)
            ToolsCore_CFRunLoop(state);
        #else
            g_main_loop_run(state->ctx.mainLoop);
        #endif
        }
        ToolsCoreCleanup(state);
        return state->ctx.errorCode;
        #endif
  }

int
ToolsCore_Run(ToolsServiceState *state)
{
    return ToolsCoreRunLoop(state);
}
```

Is there anyone who can give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Missing return between `#endif` and `}`.

Comment: The line `Here is what I add` is actually the last line of the function, after preprocessing  (the rest of the lines of the function are a `#if 0` ... `#endif` block which translates to no code)

Comment: Oh...According to your comment, I think I need to remove the #if 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing return between `#endif` and `}`.

> But there is return word in the bottom of the function.

No there isn't a `return`.

The following is one big comment with `#if 0`

```
   #if 0
    if (!ToolsCore_LoadPlugins(state)) {
      return 1;
    }
    #if defined(__linux__)
    if (state->mainService) {
      ToolsCore_InitVsockFamily(state);
    }  
    #endif
    if (state->ctx.errorCode == 0 &&
       (state->ctx.isVMware ||
        ToolsCore_GetTcloName(state) == NULL ||
        state->debugPlugin != NULL)) {
        ToolsCore_RegisterPlugins(state);

        if (g_signal_lookup(TOOLS_CORE_SIG_IO_FREEZE,
                      G_OBJECT_TYPE(state->ctx.serviceObj)) != 0) {
          g_signal_connect(state->ctx.serviceObj,
                      TOOLS_CORE_SIG_IO_FREEZE,
                      G_CALLBACK(ToolsCoreIOFreezeCb),
                      state);
        }

        state->configCheckTask = g_timeout_add(CONF_POLL_TIME * 1000,
                                         ToolsCoreConfFileCb,
                                         state);

        #if defined(__APPLE__)
            ToolsCore_CFRunLoop(state);
        #else
            g_main_loop_run(state->ctx.mainLoop);
        #endif
        }
        ToolsCoreCleanup(state);
        return state->ctx.errorCode;
        #endif
```

A better formatting will show things clearer.

```
static int ToolsCoreRunLoop(ToolsServiceState *state) {

  if (!ToolsCore_InitRpc(state)) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (state->ctx.rpc && !RpcChannel_Start(state->ctx.rpc)) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (state->ctx.rpc) {
    ToolsCoreReportVersionData(state);
  }

  //return 0; Here is what I add

#if 0
  if (!ToolsCore_LoadPlugins(state)) {
    return 1;
  }
#if defined(__linux__)
  if (state->mainService) {
    ToolsCore_InitVsockFamily(state);
  }
#endif
  if (state->ctx.errorCode == 0 &&
      (state->ctx.isVMware ||
          ToolsCore_GetTcloName(state) == NULL ||
          state->debugPlugin != NULL)) {
    ToolsCore_RegisterPlugins(state);

    if (g_signal_lookup(TOOLS_CORE_SIG_IO_FREEZE,
            G_OBJECT_TYPE(state->ctx.serviceObj)) != 0) {
      g_signal_connect(state->ctx.serviceObj,
          TOOLS_CORE_SIG_IO_FREEZE,
          G_CALLBACK(ToolsCoreIOFreezeCb),
          state);
    }

    state->configCheckTask = g_timeout_add(CONF_POLL_TIME * 1000,
        ToolsCoreConfFileCb,
        state);

#if defined(__APPLE__)
    ToolsCore_CFRunLoop(state);
#else
    g_main_loop_run(state->ctx.mainLoop);
#endif
  }
  ToolsCoreCleanup(state);
  return state->ctx.errorCode;
#endif

// Missing return

}
```

Comment: OK. I know the problem.  #if 0 is not I want. I should remove it and check the code again, thanks.